# Checking printer permissions in network slow

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, permissions, remote-access

another day, another script i guess. I have already wrote a script which checks the permissions of shared printers in a rather large enviorenment. I've already done this with SMB Shares which works fine. However checking the shares printer permissions works but it is unbearable slow.

To get the computers in question with some excludes:

```
$ADComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "DC-*"' | Where-Object { $excludeList -notcontains $_.name }
```

After that i that i get a list of printers from each system:

```
$Printer = @()
foreach ($compname in $ADComputer.Name){
    try {
        #Write-Host "Read Data of $($compname)"
        $Printerrow = Get-Printer -ComputerName $compname -Full -ErrorAction STOP # Silent Errors
        $Printer += $Printerrow
    } 
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Spoolerservice on host $($compname) not available."
    }
}
```

After this step i filter out some printers i don't want like PDF printer stuff.
The last bit of code checks the permissions:

```
ForEach ($objekt in $PrintersFiltered) {
    Try { 
        if($object.Shared -eq $true) {
            $Permissions = Convert-SDDLToACL $object.PermissionSDDL | Select-Object Name -Expand IdentityReference | Select-Object -Expand Value
            if ($Permissions-eq "Everyone") {
                Write-Warning "$($objekt.ComputerName) - $($objekt.name) - Error!"
                $ErrorCount++
            }
        }
    } 
    catch {
        break
    }
}
```

My guess is that it is this line  `$Printerrow= Get-Printer -ComputerName $compname -Full -ErrorAction STOP # Silent Errors` that makes the script so slow. Because it takes a long time if one of the spoolersevices on a server does not responde.

Does anyone have a idea / hint on how to make this faster?
Is there a way to get a list of printers with the "Invoke-Command" function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you doing with `$Printer`?

Comment: like i said it gets filtered and the filtered entires go into $PrintersFiltered

Comment: `$Printers = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()` and 
`$Printers.AddRange(Get-Printer -ComputerName $compname ...)`
should speed up a bit the script.
If does exist a built-in `ConvertFrom-SddlString` cmdlet.
$Permissions is a list of permissions. You should iterate over each ACE (access control entry).
You should check if this `PermissionSDDL` is an empty string first. 
And last, you can access value of an `IdentityReference` as `$Permissions[0].IdentityReference.Value`

Comment: @Hazrelle Thank you for the help. I will adjust my script and see if it makes a difference :)